# How to write xml string to file and download it using WCF?

Tags: asp.net, xml, wcf, c#-4.0

I have a requirement to download xml file using WCF WebGet method.

I have xml string prepared, and I just want to write it to some file and then download it.

```
        public string xmlString = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8"" standalone=""no""?>
<NamedRecon>
  <Recon>
    <Name>Accounting Cash Performance 2 Assets</Name>
    <Description></Description>
    <Type>Accounting Cash</Type>
    <FundName>IVP</FundName>
    <PBName>JPMC</PBName>
    <reportviewerid></reportviewerid>
    <is_month_end>false</is_month_end>
    <is_continuity_enabled>false</is_continuity_enabled>
    <recon_frequency_id>1</recon_frequency_id>
    <fund_mail_ids></fund_mail_ids>
    <pb_mail_ids></pb_mail_ids>
    <recon_tags></recon_tags>
    <NormalizedView>
      <Name></Name>
    </NormalizedView>
  </Recon>
</NamedRecon>";
```

I guess I am not clear here, so let me put more thoughts. Basically I am not facing any error. I have requirement that

1. I need to get data from database.
2. convert those data into xml string.
3. write that xml string into file and download it using WCF method.

I have completed 1 and 2 and as I am new to WCF so need some help for 3rd point. Any help would be appreciated.

**Basically there is a button in UI on click of that I need to download a xml file.**

Comment: WCF is able to return XML natively. Why write it to a file?

Comment: @GalacticCowboy basically there is a button in UI on click of that I need to download xml file.

Comment: A file is a box of bytes. When you "download" a file, one takes the bytes out of a file, feed it through a hose (called the internet) and on the other side, we pour the bytes into another box. Why do you want to put those bytes into a file before we send them across the internet?

Comment: @Aron there is a feature where I need to download xml file. I have prepared the xml now need to write it into some file so that I can use that file while upload in different machine.

Comment: No YOU DONT. The steps are more correctly, 1) Read object from DB 2) Send object using WCF.

Comment: To fix your code it would be more correctly 1) Read object from DB 2) Convert Object to XML String 3) Write String to File 4) Read File to String 5) Send string using WCF. You can't "send files" using WCF just like you can't "send" a piece of paper by email.

Comment: As @Aron said, you are getting hung up on the concept of a "file". Once you write it to a file, you would have to read the contents back into a string in order to send over WCF so you would be exactly where you were before writing to a file, just with a couple extra steps. Plus, interacting with the file system means you have additional security concerns, storage cost, file management (how the files get cleaned up), etc.

Comment: thanks All, now I am able to understand what I need to do here. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a method that returns a XmlElement, it's very simple:

```
 public XmlElement ReturnXml ()
        {
            public string xmlString = @".....";
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.Load(new System.IO.StringReader(xmlString));
            return doc.DocumentElement;
        }
```

Hope it helps

Comment: basically there is a button in UI on click of that I need to download xml file

Comment: the code above will work for you, you can load your file to a string using XmlDocument.Load()